# Where can I find Genimotion logs?

Tags: logfiles

Failed to drag-&-drop *.apk* into genimotion.com virtual device (emulator). Where can I find Genimotion logs? See a shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Where can I find Genimotion logs?

You need to generate the logs:

**Generating virtual device logs**

> In some cases, notably for assistance purposes, you may need to generate a log archive, either for a specific virtual device or for all virtual devices. Follow either of the procedures below:
>
> **For one virtual device**
>
> From the Genymotion main window:
>
> - Right-click on the virtual device.
> - Click Generate log archive.
> - Select the path to save the generated archive.
> - By default, log files are stored in the following folders:
>
>   ```
>    Windows: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\<virtual device name>\Logs
>    Mac OS X: $HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/<virtual device name>/
>    Linux: $HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/<virtual device name>/
>   ```
>
>   Wait until the archive is generated and click Close.

Source [Generating virtual device logs](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Generating_virtual_device_logs.htm)